# Laravel artisan error

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I started learning Laravel today.

Everything went well, but now suddenly I get an error when I try to create a controller with artisan.

My command:

```
php artisan make:controller CardsController
```

The error I get:
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class 'Routee' not found.

Working with windows 10 and Wamp.

What could cause this?

Comment: Can you try composer install one more time sometimes it doesn't load all required files.

Answer (score 0):

*blush* I had a misspelling in the routes file. duh

Answer (score 0):

Please check the folder in which you are trying to run **artisan** command. It should be in the **root directory** of your project.